# How to compute sum of angles from sine and cossine?

Tags: trigonometry

What is the fastest way to know if the `a + b > pi`, having only sine and cossine of both `a` and `b`? I am hoping to not have to use `arccos` or `arcsin`.

Edit: forgot to mention that `a` and `b` are in range [0, pi).

Comment: You can't, unless you restrict your values of `a` and `b` to be in some specific domain. [0,2pi) maybe?

Comment: Oh, yes. I forgot. a and b are in range [0, pi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the restriction of the angles domain to [0, pi) that's straightforward. You just have to check if `sin(a+b) < 0` and if you already know sin and cos of a and b, then:

`sin(a + b) = sin(a)*cos(b) + sin(b)*cos(a)`

is what you want.

Comment: Thus, suffices to check if `sin(a)*cos(b) < -sin(b)*cos(a)`.